Is "conversational" used correctly in this context?
I wonder if the 'conversational' used in this context is correct or not:

If you get an interview, study the job description like you're studying for a final exam. If there's anything in the job description that you're not familiar with, do some research to at least become conversational about it. You wanted motivation? Well, there is no motivation quite like having an interview in a day or two that you are not prepared for. I guarantee you'll be motivated to learn what you need to know to have an intelligent discussion about certain technologies in the interview.

To my ears, I think the above paragraph flows fluently and articulates its ideas clearly without any awkward transitions and wording errors. The author, whose nationality or native language I cannot identify, meant that they should do some research so that they could at least discuss the topic comfortably with the interviewers.
However, I have not found any sense of that word fitting in this context. Does it sound native and natural to your ears?

After writing my answer it's just occurred to me to check. Did you write the cited text yourself? That would certainly explain a lot!

@FumbleFingers No. And I cannot verify the nationality of the author.

Actually, looking even more carefully at the full text, I'd say if it is from a non-native Anglophone, they've got incredibly good command of "conversational, informal" English`. Which is unlikely, because any nns that good would probably know how to use the relatively more formal term conversant. Most likely it's as I first thought - a native Anglophone perfectly "fluent" in his own language - he just never noticed (and / or wasn't taught / didn't pay attention in class) the difference between conversation and conversant.

The only other (slightly) unusual element In the text is that most of us would put at least before the MAIN verb (do), rather than before the verb in the subordinate construction (become). In this exact cited sentence, it's not too noticeable, but this chart shows a very strong preference for should at least try to... over should try to at least..., which is the same basic construction.

If you are granted or given an interview. get is awful there.

"Precisely" isn't used correctly in the title though.

Should it be 'correctly' or 'appropriately'? @Flater Updated. Please check! Thanks.

@LernerZhang: It's not necessarily a mutually exclusive decision between those options.

I think 'erroneously' and 'correctly' are mutually exclusive adjectives, but both would be appropriate for the title. Am I right?

@FumbleFingers Just saw your comment here now (after I commented on your answer). I think you’re completely misreading the sentence;  at least definitely does not belong with do, but with become conversational. It’s not saying the least you can do is some research to become knowledgeable about the unfamiliar thing, but suggesting to do a bit of research, which won’t make you an expert, but may at least make you conversational about it (= know enough that you can participate in a conversation about it without being completely lost).

@JanusBahsJacquet: You guys must just think what you think. I'm in no doubt the text is badly written, and I don't really care what the writer meant to say, or what the words he actually used mean. He's confused about the meaning and syntax of conversational and conversant. To me, that's all that matters, but I've become so bored with trying to convince people who want to defend the cited tex that I've half a mind to just delete my answer. As my final comment, I'll just say become conversational about has zero currency, be conversant with is common.

@FumbleFingers The addition of the prepositional phrase is certainly less common, but this sense of conversational absolutely has currency. It’s perfectly commonplace, and it’s not a confusion with conversant, which means something entirely different, almost the opposite.

The person who wrote the text doesn't have great command of English. It's pretty obvious to me that what he was trying to convey was...

...[you should] do some research to at least become conversant with it.


conversant (Merriam-Webster)
(as in acquainted)
having information especially as a result of study or experience

Obviously in this exact context, being conversant with something in the job description doesn't mean fully conversant (intimately familiar, very knowledgeable about) - it just means the addressee should do a bit of background reading so he knows something about it.
...with the further implication (because conversant and conversation are etymologically linked) that the addressee should be capable of holding up his end of the conversation if the interviewer starts talking about something in the job description that the addressee doesn't have extensive personal experience of. It's just the similarity of form that caused the writer to pick the wrong phrasing.

Note that "become conversational" isn't really a natural sequence in English, but if anyone did use it, they'd probably use preposition about before identifying the specific relevant subject matter. But the preposition after conversant is always with [subject matter].

Also note that in general use, if someone is described as being conversant with [some area of competence / technology], this doesn't really carry any implication that they can talk about it. It means they can use that technology. The cited writer has erroneously conflated two distinct usages in a very specific context.

"The person who wrote the text doesn't have great command of English" —Well, or they made a single mistake; it happens. And the rest of the post seems quite reasonable. Personally, if I were editing it, I'd skip "conversant" entirely and go with "... to at least be able to converse about it."

@AndyBonner: It's not like inattentively writing their instead of they're. The writer clearly doesn't know the correct use of conversant, and consequently he's taken on board some completely spurious rational connected with conversation. The applicant clearly won't be able to have very much of a "conversation" about those areas of the job description that he has no experience of, and the writer's (misplaced?) at least obviously acknowledges this. The applicant would look ignorant if he tried to truly converse on a subject he only just read about.

Oh, I'm not defending the usage; I'm just saying, this is a single real user on the greater SE site, and reading through that post (without bothering to stalk-read all their posts), "doesn't have great command of English" seems unwarranted. "Doesn't know the usage of 'conversational'" is more objectively incontrovertible. The intent is explicated by the later sentence "...show them that you have at least some familiarity with language A and can hold a conversation about it." So yeah, I think the advice is to "know 'at least' the book-learning basics." ...

... And as an interviewer that counts for something with me! If I have to choose between someone who knows topic A through years of experience and someone who doesn't, easy. But if I have to choose between somebody who obviously googled it for the first time yesterday, but gets the gist, and somebody who didn't bother to do even that, then I must conclude that if the second person cares so little for the job that they didn't do even a few hours of research, they'll bring the same attitude to its execution.

I agree completely with your most recent comment above, but not really the one before that. What we're talking about here is an interview off the back of an application complete with CV, I'm sure. The interviewer should either already know or quickly discover that the applicant doesn't have significant experience of [some technique mentioned in the job description]. And it would be a foolish applicant who tried to bluff his way past that on the basis of some background reading. All the applicant needs to do is show that at least he knows of that technique, not all about it.

Yeah, I don't think it's encouraging misrepresentation. The post says that there's a high demand for software developers at the moment (note, in 2012), and I think the point is that employers can't always get hands-on experience in the desired tech, and might settle for assiduous preparation. (I got a similar vote of confidence when I transitioned from professional violinist to software developer in 2018: I had no experience with the framework being used, but was given a few days between 1st and 2nd interview to learn enough to give some sample code.)

I know it's not encouraging misrepresentation! The advice given is good. I was making the point that the cited writer isn't (or at least shouldn't be) encouraging the addressee to attempt to engage in conversation with the interviewer about a subject he has no direct experience of (to try and "bluff" his way into the job). He just needs to avoid being caught out by the interviewer mentioning the subject and the applicant having no idea what it is (is it a programming language? an operating system? a processor architecture?).

I think we're on the same page. But there can still be a "conversation" to be had: I've actually asked before, "I know you haven't worked with X, but can you tell me the basic gist of what it's about? Like, how would you explain the basic purpose of X to someone who'd never heard of it before?" And I've had applicants be able to give a coherent answer and bird's-eye explanation of X, and that makes me confident that they can pick up the mechanics of working with it, and more importantly, understand why they're using it and what the end goal is.

Well, I think you implied earlier that you had professional experience of interviewing (as the hiring company's representative, not the applicant! :). I don't know if that was specifically in the context of IT, but that specific domain been the entirety of my experience. And whereas certain "sub-domains" might be part of the overall job description, I normally only cared about the applicant having a good working knowledge of the core skills (can you design and code a full application in C++?, say). As long as you know of the Visual Studio workbench we use, that's all I want.

I have to disagree with this answer. This is a perfectly natural and idiomatic use of conversational to me, and conversant wouldn’t fit at all. Being conversant with something means being knowledgeable and experienced, having quite a lot of knowledge about it. The meaning of conversational here is almost the opposite, the same as when you aim to become conversational in a foreign language (in which context become conversational is also very common): knowing just enough to be able to have a simple conversation, without reaching any level of actual fluency.

@JanusBahsJacquet May I ask which country you are living in? I thought there might be differences between areas. Or could you please just flesh out your comment into an answer? Thanks!

@LernerZhang: Good as his English is, Janus isn't a native Anglophone. Non-native speakers obviously have the concept of wishing to acquire sufficient fluency to hold a conversation in English - a natural aspiration for "conversational ability". But that term and its referent don't really mean anything to native Anglophones (who aren't known for having such aspirations in respect of other languages! :)

@FumbleFingers Hats off to your detailed explanation! How I wish such an adjective existed! It would be very convenient to express this capability in any context.

Having read the original post on workplace.se, it seems to me the author has a good command of English for a software engineer. In this case, it also seems to me that they happen to have inserted a neologism into their text, although perhaps I'm just behind the times and this meaning will soon be found in dictionaries. Even if such a verb were recognized, however, I'd still rather write, "at least be able to talk about it."

I do think this answer is off the mark, since I see no reason to think that the author of the passage would have used the word conversant if they'd known about it. It seems to me rather that they clearly meant exactly what Janus thinks they meant. There was no conflation of ideas; merely a non-standard use of a word. Native speakers do this sometimes, especially if they're not professional writers (and sometimes even if they are, when there is no copy editor to correct them).

@Fumble That’s not quite true – while I wasn’t brought up in an English-speaking country, I did grow up bilingually, speaking English (and Danish) at home.

@JanusBahsJacquet: Well, I still think by the nature of your background the word "conversational" is likely to be useful with the general sense of "capable of holding a conversation" (by virtue of fluency in a language), which is a relatively meaningless concept to a (typically monolingual) native Anglophone. And the cited example in this question extends that "already unusual" term to "capable of holding a conversation ...about a specific subject, by virtue of having studied that subject", which is not a meaning recognized by dictionaries / native Anglophones for "conversational".

@Fumble While I can’t find the extended meaning in any dictionaries either, I have absolutely heard it many times from native English speakers. I’m trying to think if perhaps they’ve all happened to be Americans; that may be the case. I wouldn’t be at all surprised if it’s a fairly recent extension, but it is a thing used by native speakers (monoglots or not). The first paragraph of this blog post is an archetypal example of the sort of usage I’m familiar with.

@JanusBahsJacquet: I did find a single written instance of I can speak conversational French [...but I don't have full fluency in the language]. But I have to say that just looks weird to me. For most people, being able to actually hold a conversation in a foreign language (as opposed to, say, order food and drink, and "get by") would represent a pretty lofty ambition. So being (minimally) "conversational" about a subject one knows little about kinda inverts the meaning of the term anyway.

...and the full OED definition conversational Of persons: Ready to converse; very fond of conversation; gifted with powers of conversation pretty much requires being fully conversant with the language one is holding conversations in. But we're not talking about whether the cited text is comprehensible or not, or whether we can understand why the person wrote it - the question is whether it's correct. I say it ain't.

"Conversational" often implies informality and the lowest level of meaningful (oral) competency in a language, which, as you note, is still a lofty ambition, but not all Anglophones are the same. In Canada, for example, "conversational" is a standard descriptor for claiming proficiency in a language that you do not wish to claim fluency in and the government census uses "conversational" as a minimum level to count languages you speak. https://www.google.com/search?q="conversational+in+french"+site:.ca

And the usage extending to other areas is not unknown. “You don’t need to become an expert,” added Causton. “You just
have to become conversational in the topic.” http://hrprofessionalnow.ca/_Archives/2014/HRPro-May2014.pdf

@xngtng: Earlier in that text, the cited speaker (Causton) said “That’s why it’s important for people to build their financial muscles a bit.” That's less than perfect English in my book. Even Canadian "Professors of Accounting" are capable of mixing up conversant and conversational, if you search far enough.

@FumbleFingers While it may not be standard English, I don't think that the OP and the professor were mixing up "conversant" and "conversational." They likely used "conversational" with the specific meaning of "less than fluent" or "in informal/ superficial/routine discussions" (at least, this is what I expect Canadian speakers to mean in professional contexts), even if the usage is not perfect, whereas, to me, "conversant" generally would suggest familiarity in the sense of depth and breadth of knowledge (instead of informality).

Obviously, there are people who do not understand it or consider it a bad usage, and perhaps ELLs should be cautioned or discouraged from using it this way. However, my only objection to the answer is that "conversant" isn't really a replacement here, since as your answer also notes, there is a connotation that might not be intended by the author, and often conversant does not imply anything particular about holding a conversation.

The full (subscription-only) Oxford English Dictionary contains no definition corresponding to conversational = well enough informed about something / sufficiently fluent in a foreign language  to engage in conversation about / in it. Just because a few instances can be found hardly justifies teaching this as a valid usage to non-native speakers. But if people insist on using / defending it, I'm not gonna witter on forever. I'm done dealing with this one.
